# how to generate thrashing in linux?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, cpu

I want to observe [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)) in Linux.
So I tried to create many process by infinite loop in c code.
This is the code that generate thrashing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void){
        pid_t pid;
        int i=0, status, sum;
        int n[8000] = {0};

        while(i<100){
                pid = fork();
                if(pid>0){      //parent
                        i++;
                        if(i<100) continue;
                        else{
                                i=0;
                                sleep(1);
                                continue;
                        }
                        return 0;
                }
                else if(pid==0){        //child
                        printf("child : %d exit \n", getpid());
                        while(1){
                                for(i=0;i<8000;i++){
                                        sum+=n[i];
                                }
                        i=0;
                        }
                        printf("sum = %d\n", sum);      //put it in while
                        return 0;
                        }
                else{
                        fprintf(stderr, "fork error");
                        return 1;
                }
        }
}
```

but I faced fork error. so I changed the /etc/security/limits.conf to unlimited.

```
*       hard    nofile  10000
*       soft    nofile  10000
*       hard    nproc   unlimited
*       soft    nproc   unlimited
*       hard    stack   65536
*       soft    stack   65536
```

but still I faced fork error. I want to show the cpu efficiency's decrease like from 100 to 70(about) by thrashing.

Comment: You are `fork`ing up to 100 children per second, and never collecting any of them.  Even if the system does not enforce a specific limit on the number of processes you have running, it is plausible to think that you would exhaust available resources this way.

Comment: I don't think adding 8000 ints will take long enough for the process not to just execute and exit in one time slice.  To do what you want, maybe use a smaller number of long-running, CPU-bound processes.  The number just has to be 2-3 times more than the number of cores.

Comment: Moreover, your strategy for producing thrashing seems unlikely to succeed.  You are launching a large number of processes that run quickly and have low per-process memory usage.  You don't particularly need many processes, but you *do* need them to access a lot of memory, and to keep accessing it long enough to contend with the others for physical memory.

Comment: On linux you can simulate having less physical memory with the `max_addr` parameter to force swapping sooner.